# Java Decoder base64

Tags: java, servlet, base64, webix

На сервлете есть такой код:

```
try {
    List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
        new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;
    for(FileItem item : multiparts){
        if(!item.isFormField()){
            String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
            item.write( new File("C:\\temp" + File.separator + name));

            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(File.separator + name);
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
            image = ImageIO.read(bis);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(imageByte));
            System.out.println(image);
            bis.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ignore) {
}
```

Пытаюсь тут `image` закодировать в `base64` но у меня `image` почему то `null`, что я делаю не так?

```
{
    id: "upl1",
    view: "uploader",
    icon: "upload",
    type: "iconButton",
    label: "Загрузить",
    width: 110,
    align: 'center',
    multiple: false,
    link: "mylist",
    formData: {},
    on: {
        onBeforeFileAdd: function (item) {
            this.define('formData', {fileName: item.name});
            var type = item.type.toLowerCase();
            if (type != "png" && type != "jpg"){
                messageBox('Ошибка', "Только png или jpg файлы");
                return false;
            }
        },
        onAfterFileAdd: function (item) {
        },
        onUploadComplete: function (response) {
            // uploadComplete(response);
        }
    },
    upload: "/labMarket/import"
}
```

Вот код клиента. Сервлет картинку видит, тестил - сохраняет в указанную папку. А вот декодировать не получается.

Comment: `String decode = Base64
.getEncoder()
.encodeToString(
(name)
.getBytes()
);
`
попробуйте вот так

Comment: Расширю предыдущий  комментарий **decoder** - раскодирует/дешифрует **encoder** - кодирует/шифрует

Comment: ...и на всякий случай уточню Вы же в курсе что используя этот кодировщик Вы увеличиваете размер передаваемого файла на треть?

Comment: нет мне надо профиль в базу виде байта хранить какой кодировщик использовать будет лучше пока не знаю

Comment: @AslanKussein Ок а на стороне клиента вы шифруете? btoa()  возвращает вам строку?И на месте дешифрирует корректно?

Comment: @AslanKussein если все так то остается только вопрос в библиотеке мне лично чаще всего использовать [Base64](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) - Apache Commons

Comment: @peter-slusar, пока в клиенте я ничего не шифрую не совсем разобрался